# How to create public and private members?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit confused, how can I create public and private members.

My code template so far is like:

```
(function()){
   var _blah = 1;

   someFunction = function() {
     alert(_blah);
   };

   someOtherFunction = function() {
     someFunction();
   }
}();
```

Comment: You're missing the `()` after the second function keyword. Should be `someOtherFunction = function()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to use the [Yahoo Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/):

```
myModule = function () {

    //"private" variables:
    var myPrivateVar = "I can be accessed only from within myModule."

    //"private" method:
    var myPrivateMethod = function () {
        console.log("I can be accessed only from within myModule");
    }

    return {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as myModule.myPublicProperty."

        myPublicMethod: function () {
            console.log("I'm accessible as myModule.myPublicMethod.");

            //Within myProject, I can access "private" vars and methods:
            console.log(myPrivateVar);
            console.log(myPrivateMethod());
        }
    };
}();
```

You define your private members where `myPrivateVar` and `myPrivateMethod` are defined, and your public members where `myPublicProperty` and `myPublicMethod` are defined.

You can simply access the public methods and properties as follows:

```
myModule.myPublicMethod();    // Works
myModule.myPublicProperty;    // Works
myModule.myPrivateMethod();   // Doesn't work - private
myModule.myPrivateVar;        // Doesn't work - private
```

Comment: I personally like to define all the functions (public and private) as variables, and then just expose the public ones as myPublicMethod: myPublicMethod.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You don't.</del> [You can rely on convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383850/private-method-naming-convention), prepending `_` to your private attributes, and then not touching them with code that shouldn't be using it.

**Or** you can [use the function scope to create variables](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) that can't be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript every object member is public. Most popular way of declaring the private field is to use the underscore sign in it's name, just to make other people aware that this is private field:

```
a = {}
a._privateStuff = "foo"
```

The other way to hide the variable is using the scopes in javascript:

```
function MyFoo {
    var privateVar = 123;
    this.getPrivateVar = function() {
        return privateVar;
    }
}

var foo = new MyFoo();

foo.privateVar // Not available! 
foo.getPrivateVar() // Returns the value
```

Here's the article that explains this technique in details:

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 1):

**Three things:**

1. **IIFEs:**
   It seems like you need to refresh your knowledge regarding this pattern. Have a look at [this](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) post before using an IIFE again.
2. **Global public vs. Safe public:**
   Skipping `var` keyword with `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction` leads to registration of these function objects in the global scope, i.e., these functions can be called and reassigned from anywhere in the code. That could lead to some serious bugs as the code grows bigger in size. Instead, as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908/daniel-vassallo) suggested, use the module pattern. Though you can use other methods too like Constructors, Object.create(), etc, but this is pretty straightforward to implement.

   ```
   /* create a module which returns an object containing methods to expose. */
    var someModule = (function() {  
        var _blah = 1;  
         return {  
           someFunction: function() {},  
           someOtherFunction: function() {}  
         };  
    })(); 
   /* access someFunction through someModule */
   someModule.someFunction();
   // ...
   // ....
   /* after 500+ lines in this IIFE */
   /* what if this happens */  
   someFunction = function() {  
       console.log("Global variables rock.");  
   };  
   /* Fortunately, this does not interfere with someModule.someFunction */
   ```
3. **Convention and scope combined:**
   We cannot expect from every developer to follow the underscore or the capitalization convention. What if one of them forgets to implement this technique. Instead of just relying upon the convention (`_private`, `GLOBAL`) and the scope (function scoping), we can combine both of them. This helps in maintaining consistency in coding style and provides proper member security. So, if next time somebody forgets to capitalize their globals, the console (in strict mode) can prevent the world from ending.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have true private members. You have to abuse scope if your really need privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this URL will solve your problem...see that...

http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/14/javascript-how-to-get-private-privileged-public-and-static-members-properties-and-methods/