# Uncaught TypeError while generating a random position for the food in a HTML5 snake game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scope, while-loop

I am currently working on making a multiplayer Snake game in HTML5 Canvas with Javascript.

The code below is function that handles the random placement of food for the snake. The problem with the piece of code is that it give me the x and y in while(map[x][y]); back as something he can not read even though it does generate a random number.

This is the exact error:

```
    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '20' of undefined"
```

The '20' is the random generated number (and will be the grid position of the food in a two dimensional array) and changes every time I restart the program or refresh the webpage. Can someone explain what I need the change in order to define x and y and place my food?

```
                   function rand_food(){
                        var x, y;

                        do {
                            x = MR() * this.rect_w|0;
                            y = MR() * this.rect_h|0;
                        } 
                        while (map[x][y]);       <-- Here is the error                                              
                            map[x][y] = 1;

                            this.ctx.strokeRect(x * 10+1, y * 10+1, 8, 8);                                      
                    }
```

Here is another code snippet which defines the map.

```
                this.map = [];
                    // Map positions
                    //*
                    for (i = 0; i < this.rect_w; i++){
                        map[i] = [];
                }//*/
```

After trying Sean's suggestion my code now looks like this: But it still gives me same error. Any other suggestion?

```
function SnakeGame(){                       
                    this.map = [];

                    for (i = 0; i < this.rect_w; i++){
                        this.map[i] = [];                           
                    }


                    function rand_food(){
                        var x, y;
                        console.log("Map length: " + this.map.length);
                        do {
                            x = MR() * this.rect_w|0;
                            y = MR() * this.rect_h|0;
                            console.log("x: " + x);
                            console.log("y: " + y);
                        } 
                        while (this.map[x][y]);                                                     
                            this.map[x][y] = 1;

                            this.ctx.strokeRect(x * 10+1, y * 10+1, 8, 8);  

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.map` and `map` are not the same thing.

If you are inside an object then `this.map` is a public variable of the object, and `map` is a local variable.

Try something like this:

```
this.map = [];
// Map positions
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    this.map[i] = [];
}
```

and in the `rand_food` function also use `this.map`.

Here are two possible ways you can go:

```
//using public variable
function SnakeGame() {
    this.map = [];
    // Map positions
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        this.map[i] = [];
    }

    function rand_food() {
        // refer to this.map here
        this.map[0];
    }
};

// using local variable
function SnakeGame() {
    var map = [];
    // Map positions
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        map[i] = [];
    }

    function rand_food() {
        // refer to map here
        map[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: See also the [Module Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803323/how-to-create-public-and-private-members) for a slightly different approach

Comment: What about the MR function, this.rect, and this.ctx? These should all be declared in the containing object as well (which you seem to have made SnakeGame now). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg602402) is a good introductory article on OO in javascript, it might help clear things up.

Comment: The MR function is a local variable, the rect_w and rect_h are public variables and the ctx is public too. I made them all the same (public) using "this." but nothing has worked so far. Thanks for the article, I just read that but it didn't add much to solving my problem. 

I will now continue breaking my head over this issue. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Is it possible to link to a public version of what you have, so we can look at the code in context?

Comment: Alright, sorry for my late response but I didn't have time anymore to look at it yesterday. Had other things to work. You can download the project here [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?aoy72x86iesdjbx) . open the .rar and look at the Snake2.html and inside the JS folder for the snake.js. Those are the files I am working in. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If map was not defined you would normally get a ReferenceError, so map is defined but probably:

- not assigned to anything
- defined/assigned after beeing used
- hoisted by beeing defined in a condition that do not execute

example

```
if (0) {
    var foo = 1;
}
console.log(foo) //= undefined
console.log(foo[20]) // TypeError…
console.log(bar) // ReferenceError…
```